# DOMPDF Font Issue On Server

Tags: php, fonts, dompdf

i am using DOMPDF for PDF creation and its working fine on local server but when i upload the files on server it showing me the font error.please help me out.error is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/clients/client65/web343/web/admin/pdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/Font.php on line 9

Comment: Could you update your question and include the code you'll find in line 9 of Font.php?

Comment: The issue is with some library code, not anything the poster created. [Line 9](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/blob/0.2.2/classes/Font.php#L9) is before any code in that library and more than likely the files were corrupted on upload, you should try to upload a fresh copy.

Comment: (Also, since you're uploading a fresh copy you should make sure it's [0.6.2](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.6.2))